# How to refer to Field Name with a ? in it in MS Access VBA code

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Simple question, but I am new to databases. I have a field called 'ActorRetired?', and in some VBA code I need to set the value of it to -1. But When I try:

```
Me.ActorRetired?.Value = -1
```

I get the error 'Compile Error: Expected: Expression' with the question mark highlighted.

How do I refer to the field name without this error? So far I have tried

```
Me.[ActorRetired?].Value = -1
Me."ActorRetired?".Value = -1
```

But neither has worked. Please help!

Comment: Try `Me.ActorRetired_.value`. But I'd recommend you to rename your control/column to some name which does not contain problematic chars, for example, to `DoesActionRetired`.

Comment: @Akina Doing that gives me 'Method or data member not found' and there's a lot of things I would have to change if I changed the field name, but if there's no other solution there I will.

Comment: In VBA (form module) type `Me.` - intellisense will suggest all possible variants, look in the list for your column name as it is interpreted by VBA. When I create a table with the column named `ActorRetired?`, then create a form with this table as a rowsource using master, and then try to refer to the column's value in Form_Current - shown expression works correctly. So describe detailed what do you do...

Comment: You might need to use `Me![ActorRetired?] = -1` - it's been a good long while since I used Access, but I remember something along those lines for fields that aren't directly added as an object to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have special characters in a VBA name. The bang operator ( the `!` in `Me![ActorRetired?] = -1`) is just a shortcut for string based name lookup. It's not syntactically clear so I recommend using an actual string so it's clear that is what you want to do.

If you want to access the underlying Field using a string you would go through the form recordset like this:

```
Me.Recordset.Fields.Item("ActorRetired?").Value = -1
```

Or if you have a control of the same name you can go through the forms control collection like this:

```
Me.Controls.Item("ActorRetired?").Value = -1
```